# Django REST testing - how to specify pk argument referring to the model instance created in setUp function

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework

I have a model "Article" and I want to test if authorized user can GET an individual article.
The testing class is:

```
class TestPost(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = APIRequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='Name', email='test@company.com', password='secret')
        self.article = Article.objects.create(
            author = 'Author', title = 'Article title', body = 'Body content ...')

     def test_detail_user(self):
        request = self.factory.get(reverse('article_id', kwargs={'pk': 1}))
        request.user = self.user
        response = ArticleDetail.as_view()(request, pk=1)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200,
                        f'Expected Response Code 200 - OK, received {response.status_code} instead.')
```

The URL pattern is:

```
path('<int:pk>/', ArticleDetail.as_view(), name = 'article_id'),
```

And when running tests I get the following error:

```
f'Expected Response Code 200 - OK, received {response.status_code} instead.')
AssertionError: 404 != 200 : Expected Response Code 200 - OK, received 404 instead.
```

I suppose the problem is in the specified 'pk', but I cannot figure out how to specify pk without stating an exact figure of 1. How can I refer to the article created in setUp function instead?

Comment: you could do it by passing "self.article.id" or "self.article.pk" instead of "pk=1".

Comment: in fact, _never_ hardcode ids in testcases. for all you know the id could be 25334 in the next run, although unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding, but you should be able to reference it by simply doing something like:

```
def test_detail_user(self):
    article_id = self.article.pk
    ...
    # the rest of your code here using article_id as the id of 
    # the article you are retrieving
```